Is it possible to approximate non-causal time delay?
I have been struggling with a problem regarding a digital control theory. Namely it's a feedforward compensation for a system with a transport delay $T_d$. The problem is that in such a case the transfer function of the feedforward compensator includes inverse of the tranport delay i.e.
$$H_{ff}(s) \approx e^{s\cdot T_d}$$
It's obviously non-causal system which can be realized neither in continuous nor in discrete time domain. My question is whether it would be possible to approximate this system somehow e.g. via a digital lead compensator which is capable to bring phase lead?

If your task is to make the output of the system follow a predetermined path, just look ahead in the target position data.

It is possible to design filters with negative delay (i.e., advance) in a certain frequency band. Such filters are called predictors. Linear prediction has been used for many years, for instance in linear predictive coding. Have a look at this question and its answers for a concrete example of a 1 step predictor.
Note, however, that you always need to decide on a certain frequency band where the prediction should work (i.e., where the delay is negative), and you won't have much control over what happens outside that frequency band.

Thank you very much for your answer. May I ask you for your opinion regarding the lead compensator I have suggested above?

@Steve: A lead compensator has negative delay over some frequency band, but it won't approximate a constant negative delay very well.
